# Program1.pas(15) : Встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор

Tags: pascal, if

```
program Lab1s2;
var   Fa,Fc,a,b: real;
      f: text;
      eps:=exp(ln(10) * (-4));
      begin;
   a:=1;
   b:=2;
   x:=a;
   Fa:=exp(ln(x) * 4)-13*exp(ln(x) * 2)+(36/x);
while b-a>=2*eps do;
   c:=(a+b)/2;
   x:=c;
   Fc:=exp(ln(x) * 4)-13*exp(ln(x) * 2)+(36/x);
   if (Fa*Fc=0) then c:=a;
    else c:=b;
   c:=(a+b)/2;
procedure Write(f, 'C:\TEXT.txt'; c);
end.
```

Пишет Program1.pas(15) : Встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор. Я не могу понять в чем проблема, и как это исправить. Я только начал учиться писать на языке Pascal, раньше писал на Fortran.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Это разве Pascal? В Pascal нет end if, end do(вместо этого только begin end). Это немного другой язык.

Comment: Да, мой косяк. С фортрана сложно переходить

Comment: Попробовали бы тогда уж учить более новые языки. У паскаля никаких перспектив, это уже мертвый язык. К примеру python проще намного, и активно используется во всех областях, С подобные языки так тем более. Говорю как тот кто начинал с паскаля и жалеет о потраченном времени которое можно было уделить на С++ например.

Comment: Это не моя инициатива, университет требует. У нас на Украине вообще система образования устаревшая. Ну кому взбредет в голову что учить не то что паскаль, FORTRAN - хорошая идея.

Comment: @BogdanBida, паскаль лет 20 уже хоронят, а он все живет и живет

Comment: @Lucky Ну.. я тоже с Украины, Харьков, мы же учим с++, python, c#, java, и.т.д.

Comment: @Grundy Живет, в учебных заведениях, школах, и компаниях которые еще живут на старых стандартах

Comment: @BogdanBida, что за старые стандарты? Последние версии языка вполне отвечают последним стандартам

Comment: Как бы это выразиться... Язык - он, ну, как машина, что ли. Сел и поехал. Если не знаешь ПДД, то толку от того, насколько круто ты водишь? Главное - куда ехать, а не на чем :) Да и переучиться с одной машины на другую - не так сложно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это далеко не единственная ошибка у вас...

```
program Lab1s2;
var   x, Fa,Fc,a,b,c: real;
      f: text;
      eps: real; 
begin;
   eps := 1e-4;
   a:=1;
   b:=2;
   x:=a;
   Fa:=exp(ln(x) * 4)-13*exp(ln(x) * 2)+(36/x);
   while b-a>=2*eps do
   begin
       c:=(a+b)/2;
       x:=c;
       Fc:=exp(ln(x) * 4)-13*exp(ln(x) * 2)+(36/x);
       if (Fa*Fc >= 0) then a:=c else b:=c;
   end;
   Assign(f,'C:\TEXT.txt');
   Rewrite(f);
   Write(f, c);
   Close(f);
   Writeln(c);
end.
```

Примерно так. Сами посмотрите, где отличия. И учтите, что в корень диска C: у вас может не хватить прав писать.

Да, и все-таки пишите лучше `x*x` вместо `exp(ln(x) * 2)` - оно и проще, и быстрее, и область определения пошире :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Это моя первая программа на данном языке.

Comment: Я ожидал что ошибок будет дофига

Comment: я там поменял уже. if (Fa*Fc=0) then c:=a else c:=b

Comment: См. https://ideone.com/NonYyx - там все же нужно `>= 0`

Comment: https://ideone.com/NonYyx - я там причесал немного, посмотрите...

Comment: @Harry Файл забыли открыть и закрыть

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Охотно поверю, я Паскалил лет 20 назад... Не подправите?

Comment: Assign(f,'‪E:\Test\TEXT.txt');  - вот в такой строчке, я прислушался к совету и в корень нее кидаю. Следующая ошибка

Comment: Program1.2.pas(18) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Данный формат пути не поддерживается.

Comment: Вы работаете где? Операционная система, компилятор?

Comment: Pascal ABC, Windows 10

Comment: @Harry Поправил

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо! А ошибка "Данный формат пути не поддерживается" не с этим могла быть связана? Вроде бы нет, но... Потому что я ее что-то не понимаю.

Comment: @Harry Товарищ, что-то не договаривает. Я не вижу ошибки в этой строке

Answer (score 2):

Согласно синтаксису языка, в конструкции `if .. then .. else ..`, перед `else` в строчке `a:=c;` не должно быть точки с запятой.